# My Default.HOC.js code wrote in React has some bug which is abstaining it from rendering Default.layout.js component with its properties message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, tailwind-css

Working on React, my app has a Default.HOC.js file which is rendered as a component inside my App.js with its properties..The Default.layout.js contains a return statement associated to a message to be displayed on output screen and Default.layout.js file has been rendered as a component with its properties inside the Default.HOC.js file...Now to test whether the Default.HOC.js is properly being rendered to App.js file,I have console logged a statement in the HOC file and it is working well,but the Default.layout.js is not getting rendered in the HOC file thus preventing the message returned in layout file to be displayed in screen

Here is my Default.HOC.js file code-"

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import DefaultLayout from "../layouts/Default.layout.js";

const DefaultHOC = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log("HOC rendered");

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        element={(props) => (
          <DefaultLayout>
            <Component {...props} />
          </DefaultLayout>
        )}
        {...rest}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default DefaultHOC;
```

"

this is my App.js code - "

```
// import logo from './logo.svg';
// import './App.css';

// Deleted section inside the below function
// <div className="App">
//       <h2 className='text-aradhana-500'>Hi</h2>
// <h1 className="text-xl hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-blue-600/100">Hello Everyone</h1>
// <button className="border-2 px-2 py-1 lg:border-green-500 lg:bg-green-500 border-blue-500 md:border-red-500  rounded bg-blue-500 md:bg-red-500 text-white hover:text-blue-500 hover:bg-transparent hover:border-4">Hello</button>
//     </div>
// ----------------------------------------
//<></> such empty tags are called fragments , we use them as we want to return something using tags that we put our entire routing code into 
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom" ; 
//import HOC 
import DefaultHOC from "./HOC/Default.HOC";
//component
import Temp from "./components/Temp";

import DefaultLayout from "./layouts/Default.layout"

// function Name() {
// return <h1>Welcome to Home Page!!!</h1>;
// }

// function Name2(){
// return <h1>Welcome to Movie Page!!!</h1>
// }
//dynamically rendering functional component
// < Route exact path="/" element={<Name/>}  />
//< Route exact path="/movie"  element={<Name2/>} />

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/*"
        element={<DefaultHOC element={<Temp />} />}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}
// function App() {
//   return (
//     <Routes>
//       <Route
//         path="/"
//         element={(
//           <DefaultHOC>
//             <Route index element={<Temp />} />
//           </DefaultHOC>
//         )}
//       />
//     </Routes>
//   );
// }

export default App;
//In this version, I replaced component={<Name />} with element={<Name />} and component={<Name2 />} with element={<Name2 />}. This aligns with the correct usage of React Router v6. The element prop is used to render the React element associated with the route.
// / , /movie
//export default App;
```

"

here is my Default.layout.js code-"

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar/navbar.component"
const DefaultLayout = (props) =>
{console.log("DefaultLayout rendered");
    return (
        <>
   <Navbar />
   (props.children)
   </>
    );
};

export default DefaultLayout;
```

"

here is my Temp.js code inside a folder called components folder-"

```
import React from "react";

function Temp(){
    console.log("temp rendered");
    return (<h1>This is a temp component</h1>);
}

export default Temp;
```

"

here is my navbar.component.js code-"

```
import React from "react";
import { FaChevronRight } from "react-icons/fa6";

const NavSm = ()=> {
    return(<div>
        <div>
            <h3>It all starts here</h3>
        <span>
       Bhubaneswar <FaChevronRight />
       </span>
       </div>
    </div>
    )
};

const NavMd = ()=> {};

const NavLg = ()=> {};

const Navbar = () => {
return (
<>
<nav>
<div className="md:hidden">{
/*mobile screen*/
< NavSm />
/*md:hidden means that this division is hidden for medium and large size screens*/
}</div>

<div className="md:hidden">{
/*mobile screen*/
/*md:hidden means that this division is hidden for medium and large size screens*/
}</div>

<div className="hidden md:flex lg:hidden">{
/*tablet screen*/
}</div>

</nav>
</>
)

};

export default NavSm;
```

"